# Batch script for loops halts when an error occurs

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, curl

I have a batch script snippet that is supposed to iterate over all the files in a folder, and send them to an API using curl. Problem i am facing is during iteration if one file produces some error during curl operation, for loop stops (remainder files wont be curled (if that is a technical word). I need a way where if curl operation on a file fails, for loop continues with other files
Below is the code i am using-

```
for /R "%SourceDirectory%" %%I in (*.csv) do (
    curl --data-binary @%%~fI  -H "Content-Type: text/csv" -H "Authorization: Bearer "%secrettoken%"""" %myAPI% >> "%LogFilePath%"
)
```

Comment: There seems to be some crazy double-quoting going on, and I would suggest that `%%~fI` is double-quoted too, as you cannot be sure that it does not contain spaces or other potential poison characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`for /f + where /r`** instead **`for /r`**

```cmd
@echo off && for /f tokens^=* %%I in (%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "%SourceDirectory%" *.csv')do >>"%LogFilePath%" (
curl --data-binary @"%%~I" -H "Content-Type: text/csv" -H "Authorization: Bearer" "%secrettoken%" "%myAPI%" )
```

- **[where /?](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**

Comment: I suspect, the proper quoting of `"%%~fI"` does more benefit than the usage of `where` (not saying, usage of `where` is wrong advice)

Comment: `"%%~fI"` or `"%%~I"` was ok. Without the quotes filenames with spaces are problematic.